# Evaluating this surface integral

Tags: integration, symbolic-computation

I want to evaluate the following surface integral

$$\int_S d S \, \, \exp\left(\frac{\Gamma^2 (x^2 \sigma_x^2 + y^2 \sigma_y^2 + z^2 \sigma_z^2) - 2 c R \Gamma (x x_0 + y y_0 + z z_0)}{2 c^2 R^2}\right)$$

where $S$ describes the surface of a sphere of radius $R$, the real positive parameters $\Gamma, x_0, y_0, z_0$ define the physical system being considered, $c$ is the speed of light. The general point $\bf{r}$ = $(x, y, z)$ lies on the surface, $S$, of the sphere with radius $R$ that I am trying to integrate over.

How can I obtain an analytic expression for this? My current attempts have made no progress. I have tried `Mathematica`. I have also changed the integral into spherical coordinates using $d S = R^2 \sin\theta\ d\theta\  d\phi$ and with $x = R\sin\theta\cos\phi, y = R\sin\theta\sin\phi, z = R\cos\theta$. However, I am having difficulties in evaluating the integrals which result from this change in basis as well. For example if we consider the integral wrt $\phi$ from 0 to $2 \pi$ which results, we have:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \, \, \exp\left(\frac{\Gamma^2 (\cos^2\phi\sin^2\theta \sigma_x^2 + \sin^2\phi\sin^2\theta \sigma_y^2) - 2 c \Gamma (x_0\cos\phi\sin\theta + y_0\sin\phi\sin\theta)}{2 c^2}\right)$$

This appears to no simpler an evaluation.

Are there any other methods or substitutions that can be used to yield an analytical expression for the first integral written above?

**ADDENDUM: PHYSICAL CONTEXT OF PROBLEM:**
As a final note, the physical system that I am considering is the propagation of a photon to all points along the surface of a sphere. That is along some source plane, I have a single photon that has a 3D-Gaussian distribution (or [Multivariate][2] with 0 off diagonal terms in the [covariance matrix][3]).

As a result I have a ket (state of the photon), which is proportional to this 3D-Gaussian. In fact you can 'see' the resemblence of a Gaussian as the exponential term in the above integral. The difference is due to the propagation of this source photon to the surface of a sphere a distance $R$ away from the source. The propagator that I use is the *retarded Green's function* from electrostatics.

The requirement of normalising the state along the surface of a sphere (for unit probablities) encounters the integral above.

Comment: I don't think a closed form exists.

Comment: What are the $\sigma_x, \sigma_y$ and $\sigma_z$?

Comment: @peterag, these three variables describe the standard deviations of the three-dimensinal Gaussian that I use to model the spatial profile of the emitted photons. They are real and positive as well. Will add this to the description of my problem above.

Comment: @HenryW, I should add that a suitable approximation  the evaluation should be fine as well - though an analytic expression nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: So the $\sigma$ are all constants from the point of view  of the integral, correct?  No reason to have them equal to a common value?

Comment: @peterag, Yes they are constants in the view of the integral. I do intend to set them to the same value in the end, $\sigma_x = \sigma_y = \sigma_z = \sigma$, so if this makes the evaluation easier I am happy to do that. If possible to retain the difference then that would enable flexibility that I could utilise later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes that the $\sigma_x$, $\sigma_y$, and $\sigma_z$ are equal to a common value $\sigma$ - doing so allows one to make use of spherical symmetry.

Write $S_R$ for the sphere of radius $R$. Then, the above integral can be labeled and rewritten as $$ \phi_{(R, \Gamma, \sigma )}(y) =  \int_{S_R} d S_R \, \, \exp\left(\frac{(\Gamma\sigma)^2 R^2  - 2 c R \Gamma \,x\cdot y}{2 c^2 R^2}\right),$$
where

- $x$ ranges over the sphere $S_R$, so that $\|x\|^2 = R^2$,
- $y\in \mathbb R^3$ (i.e., $y$ is the $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ of the question),
- $x\cdot y$ denotes the dot product.

Taking out the constant factor and simplifying, one gets
$$ \phi_{(R, \Gamma, \sigma )}(y) =  \exp \left(\,(\Gamma\sigma)^2/2 c^2 \right)\int_{S_R} d S_R \, \, \exp\left(\frac{ -    \Gamma \,x\cdot y}{ c R}\right).$$

For neatness, group the terms $y$, $\Gamma$ and $c$ of the integral together, and replace the integral with one over the unit sphere (so $dS_R = R^2 dS_1$, and the $R$ cancels in the exponent, as we are replacing $x$ with $Rx$):
$$ \phi_{(R, \Gamma, \sigma )}(y) =  \exp \left(\,(\Gamma\sigma)^2/2 c^2 \right)\, R^2 \,\phi (\Gamma y/c),$$
where
$$ \phi( y ) = \int_{S_1} d S_1 \, \, \exp\,\left( - x\cdot y\right).$$

Now, by symmetry, $\phi (y)$ only depends on the magnitude of $y$, so $\phi (y) = f( \|y\| )$, where 
$$ f(r  ) = \int_{S_1} d S_1 \, \, \exp\, \left(- x\cdot kr\right),$$
with  $r\ge 0$ and $k=(0,0,1)$.

Now, $f(0) = 4 \pi$.

For $r\not = 0$:

If $\theta$ is the angle between the $k$ and $x$ ($0$ pointing northwards, $\pi$ pointing southwards) we can rewrite the above as
$$f(r) =  2\pi\int_0^\pi   \exp\, \left(-  r\cos \theta \right) \,\sin\theta \,d\theta.$$
Finally 
$$ f(r) = 2 \pi \, \left( e^r  - e^ {-r} \over r \right) = {4 \pi \sinh r \over r}.$$

Comment: Thanks! Why is $\vert\vert y \vert\vert$ written as $k r$, where the vector $k$ points in the $z$ direction? Why can we use this trick to lose the integral over $\phi$?

Comment: Since the integral is over the sphere, the direction of $y$ is irrelevant - only its (scalar) magnitude  $r=\|y\|$ matters. Therefore, we can replace $y$ with any convenient vector of the same size, e.g, $r\, k$, where $k= (0,0,1)$, which is what I did. Alternatively, if you prefer, one could set and fix $k = y/\|y\|$ (if $y\not = 0$) , and set up the spherical integration  coordinates using this fixed $k$ , instead of  the $z$ axis, as reference: $\theta$ would then be  the angle between $x$  and $k$, and $\phi$ would sweep the plane through the origin perpendicular to $k$. Is that OK?

Comment: That's great thanks.

Comment: In regards to the first point of my previous comment - of course it matters that the integrand involves only dot products. I'll add a more formal argument this evening so that I have a clean conscience...

Comment: As promised: if $\alpha$ is a rotation, then $\alpha x \cdot \alpha y = x\cdot y$  - ie., $\alpha$ is an isometry, , $\alpha$ carries a sphere $S$ to itself, and is area preserving.
Thus, for any (integrable) function $g$ on the sphere, $$ \int dS  \, g(  x ) = \int dS \, g(\, \alpha ^{-1} x \,).$$
Also $\alpha^{-1} x \cdot y = x \cdot \alpha y$.

So,  $$ \phi (y) = \int dS  \exp (x\cdot y ) = \int dS  \exp (\alpha^{-1} x\cdot y ) = \int dS  \exp ( x\cdot \alpha y ) = \phi (\, \alpha y \,).$$
Therefore $\phi(y)$ depends only on the magnitude of $y$.

Comment: And - oops -  by rotation I meant  $\alpha$ also to be orientation preserving i.e. positive determinant....

Comment: Thanks for the great posts! Can the spherical symmetry used in the above method also be used to solve the following two related integrals? Consider that we now have $$ \phi_{(R, \Gamma, \sigma )}(y) =  \int_{S_R} d S_R \, \, x_2^n \, \, \exp\left(\frac{(\Gamma\sigma)^2 R^2  - 2 c R \Gamma \,x\cdot y}{2 c^2 R^2}\right),$$ where $x_2$ is the second element of the vector $x$ which ranges over the sphere $S_R$, i.e. it is the parameter *$y$ (from $\bf{r}$ = $(x, y, z)$) in the original question*, and $n = 1$ and $2$ respectively for the two integrals related to the above question.

Comment: I should add that any valid approximation to this integral should be fine. I will probably add a separate but related question on the stack exchange. Thanks!

Comment: I  think we could do something:  it looks like $\partial^2 \phi (y)/ \partial^2 y_2$ would be pretty close to the integral that you want - do you see that (differentiate under the int sign)?if you want/need me to, I'm happy to think about it this week (by Wednesday, say) more carefully, and add it to the answer above. On the other hand, it seems to me that the taking of partial derivatives (if the idea is right/works!!!) must correspond to your actual, real question (i.e., from physics!) that you are trying to solve - i.e., moments etc Is that so? (cont)

Comment: (cont) O I didn't see your previous - "will add to stack exchange" comment - great! I think it would be worth your while to add some context (i.e. physics)  to the question (or even above as an addendum to the original question, if you decide not to add a separate question - you'll get more views with a new question obviously) - not that I have much to add, 'physics-speaking'. Let me know though.... I'm happy to help - I might have a chance before Wednesday, if you're in a hurry.

Comment: P.S. the $\phi$ in the before last comment is the $\phi$ in my answer. And I misread your question - I took $n = 2$. So it should be $\partial^n \phi / \partial y_2^n$. All the typos  I'm making! Comment section is obviously not the best place for this....

Comment: I have made a new [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667589/evaluating-this-surface-integral-2) with the updated question and an additional context to the problem. I have so far tried a series expansion to the problem which does work but it is much messier!

Comment: ok - as I said, I think there should be a closed form-version, maybe messy, if n is large, because of all the product and chain rules  - did you understand my suggestion (right or wrong), though?

Comment: Yes, thanks very much! Just realised I didn't need to post the seperate question - The differential commutes with the integral. Hence, I can just differentiate your above solution $n$ times. I think I will delete the previous post and add the addendum to this post instead! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: right, I think  so - using $r = \sqrt { y_1^2 + y_2^2 + y_3^2}$. You might post your own answer for verification purposes, if you feel like it. Let me (and the world) know if you need anything... good luck